# Comparing 2 values with 3 if conditions

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have 2 values, one in cell H5 and another on cell S5. For both of these values the cells are formatted as a percentage without decimals.

I want to create an extra cell where I get

- "↑" if S5 > H5
- "↓" IF S5 < H5
- "-" IF S5 = H5

I originally tried this

```
=IF(S5>H5,"↑", IF(S5<H5,"↓", IF(S5=H5,"-")))
```

And it works but the problem is when they are equal, so even though I changed the format cell so that its a percentage with decimals if I have 91% in both cells but the actual number is like 0.91 and 0.94 then its going to go into one of the first two cases and show one as being higher than the other.

I tried comparing the first 3 numbers in both cells with this formula but it is giving me an error so I don't know what else I can do

```
=IF((LEFT(S5,3)>LEFT(H5,3),"↑"),IF(LEFT(S5,3)<LEFT(H5,3),"↓"),IF(LEFT(S5,3)=LEFT(H5,3),"-"))
```

Comment: Use `ROUND` perhaps before comparing.

Comment: Great, this worked, I used 
=IF(ROUND(S5,2)>ROUND(H5,2),"↑", IF(ROUND(S5,2)<ROUND(H5,2),"↓", IF(ROUND(S5,2)=ROUND(H5,2),"-")))

and it seemed to do the trick

Comment: Since there are only 3 possible outcome, and an if statement gives two possibilities, you only need to check two cases.  If it is not case A and its not case B then it has to be case C.  IF(test1, Case A, IF(test2, Case B, Case C)).  So your formula could be: `=IF(ROUND(S5,2)>ROUND(H5,2),"↑", IF(ROUND(S5,2)<ROUND(H5,2),"↓", "-"))